# Fastest way to run prim's on a growing range of coordinates

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was hoping someone could give me a general method for computing the MST for a problem that works from input that is formatted as such:

```
<number of vertices>
<x> <y>
<x> <y>
...
```

I understand how to implement prim's algorithm, but I was looking for a method that (using prim's algorithm) will require the least amount of memory/time to execute.  Should I store everything in an adjacency matrix?  If the number of vertices grows to say, 10,000, what is the optimal way to solve this problem (assuming prim's is used)?

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use Prim's?

A simple way is use Kruskal algorithm to recompute the spanning tree (using only previously selected edges) every time you add a node. Since Kruskal is O(E log E) and in every iteration you'll have exactly 2*V-1 edges to compute (V-1 from previous tree + V from newly added node). You'll need O(V log V) for each insertion.

Comment: Note that both Prim's and Kruskal's algorithm can be used on the new graph (and you even have a "special" node to start from ;-) )

Comment: Prim's algoritm is faster if you have a dense graph (graph has a lot of edges).

Comment: I'm sorry, can you elaborate?  Considering that we have no idea what vertices connect to other vertices (the only assumption we can make is that that graph is complete), is kruskal's still faster than prim's?

Comment: Also, doesn't O(VlogV) for each insertion imply O(V^2logV) for total computation?  Can't we compute MST in O(V^2) using prim's + adjacency matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Prim's algoritm is faster if you have a dense graph (a graph that has a lot of edges). If you use an adjacency matrix, the complexity of Prim's algoritm would be `O(|V|^2)`.

This can be improved by using a binary heap data structure with the graph represented by an adjacency list. Using this method, the complexity would be `O(|E|log|V|)`.

Using a fibonacci heap data structure with an adjacency list would be even faster with a complexity of `O(|E| + |V|log|V|)`.

Note: `E` refers to the number of edges in the graph, while `V` refers to the number of vertexes in the graph.

The `STL` has already implemented a binary heap data structure, `std::priority_queue`. A `std::priority_queue` calls the `heap` algoritms in the algoritm library. You could also use a `std::vector` (or any other container that has random access iterators) and call `make_heap`, `push_heap`, `pop_heap`, etc. These are all in the algoritm library. More info here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/.

You could also implement your own heap data structure, but that may be too complicated and not worth the performance benefits.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't exactly help.  I know what the complexity of prim's is under certain conditions, but I'm having trouble making choices about what to do for this problem specifically.  Using an adjacency list with complexity O(|E|log|V|) would be slower than O(|V|^2) because the number of edges in this problem (a complete graph) would be |V|^2.  Thus, using a binary heap would result in   Hence, my problem.

Comment: First what you said is incorrect. `O(|E|log(|V|))` is faster than `O(V^2)`. It sounds like you want somebody to write the algoritm for you. You asked what the fastest way would be to run Prim's algoritm and that would be using a heap data structure and having your graph represented by an adjacency list. You could use an array or `std::vector` to represent the graph. Look at this link if you want actual code: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-5-prims-mst-for-adjacency-list-representation/

Comment: I don't want anyone to write anything for me, please don't assume that's the case.  How is O(|E|log(|V|)) faster than O(V^2) when E = V^2 (in a complete graph)?

Comment: In a complete graph, `E = (V(V-1))/2`, so it is not technically `V^2`. Also this link talks more about the time complexity of Prim's algorithm: http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/GraphAlgor/primAlgor.htm